# How to keep ul displayed when transfer to this

Tags: jquery, html

i'm new in programming. When hovering over div '1', a unordered list 'ul'  is displayed, already dynamically created. Because i made it from scratch ,note that '1' has no parent-child relation with ul.

JQUERY

```
$('.1').hover(function(e) {       
   $("#ul").show();
 },function(e){       

  });
```

It is obvious that according to code above, when i'm trying to move from div '1' to ul, ul disappears. That's the point: how can i keep ul displayed when transfer and hovering over it;

Comment: Provide your HTML, maybe you could actually make parent-child relation by jquery (if it was impossible on some other way, and you need it!), to keep things simple....

Answer (score 0):

try use `mouseenter()`:

```
$('.1').mouseenter(function(e) {       
   $("#ul").show();      
});
```

Comment: first phase (keeping ul displayed when transfer) is ok. But how can i hide ul when living it;

Comment: I tried :   $("#ul1"+id).mouseleave(function(e) {   
    $("#ul1"+id).hide();   
   }); with no results

Comment: what is `+id` ? try it without it

Comment: Because i create dynamically several ul , i change its name via loop

Comment: do they have any class?